# Javascript bookmarklet causes page to go blank

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I am creating a JavaScript bookmarklet to toggle the visibility of an HTML Element on a page, but it seems like just hiding the element is troublesome:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HtkzL

Code:

```
<div id="hideme">
  <p>I am a div that needs to be hidden</p>
</div>

<p>I am a paragraph that doesn't need to be hid.</p>

<blockquote>
  I am a blockquote that the whole world must see
</blockquote>

<a href="javascript:var a=document.getElementById('hideme');a.style.display='none';">Click me to hide the div.</a>
```

what's happening is that every the anchor link is clicked, the entire page goes blank and says "none".

When I inject the exact same code in the `<a> ... </a>` in a JS console, it works just fine.

Any possible fixes for the problem?

Comment: append void(0) like old-school links

Comment: @dandavis or a more standard `return false;`

Comment: return is for use inside functions...

Comment: Inline JS is bad practise and u should attach eventlistener. Im mobile, u can also try adding "return false". Also, inline CSS isnt that great either, u can add a class instead that has disp none.

Comment: @EricG If OP is creating a bookmarklet, as the question describes, then inline JS is exactly what he needs to do to achieve it.

Comment: @rgthee whats OP and why need inline? xD

Comment: @EricG "OP" = Original poster (in this case me). The JS must be inline as the `<a> ... </a>` link is to be a bookmarklet. Users drag the `<a> ... </a>` link into their Bookmarks Bar so that they can click it at any time they need it.

Comment: ty =) so u also cannot refer to functions that exist outside the inlineJS? I mean how can u assure the element with ID 'hideme' exists anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is hiding the element, but it's also following your anchor right after (to nowhere). You can return false, or a falsy value. I'd wrap it in `void` which will return undefined, but either will work. Here's your codepen and the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dsgKk

```
<a href="javascript:void(function(){ var a = document.getElementById('hideme'); a.style.display='none'; })();">Click me to hide the div.</a>
```

(This would also work, but is less clean, imo):

```
<a href="javascript:var a=document.getElementById('hideme'); a.style.display='none'; return false;">Click me to hide the div.</a>
```

Comment: confused: how does that first one work with the invocation after the void? (it does)

Comment: confused2: if the handler code is coerced into a function, then return makes sense, but why then would wrapping a function body in void(...) affect the return if said function body was without a return statement in the first place? in short, it seems the tail matters but it's amazing how little literature there is about what exactly is happening in javascript: code execution.

Comment: @dandavis Interesting. I didn't notice that at first. I can't find any information – and this is offtopic now – but if I can take a *_guess_*: `void` is a special _operator_ which does not need the parenthesis. I'm assuming the engine rips them out, akin to: `void function(){ /*...*/} ()`. You can see that `typeof` works the same way: `typeof(function(){ return 'hi'; })()` returns `"string"` not a `TypeError`... as if evaluating `typeof function(){ return 'hi'; } ()` and _not_ `"string"();`

Comment: i'll buy it. firefox has issues with the 2nd one, but chrome is pretty good about not sending to a blank page...

Answer (score -1):

```
getElementById('hideme');a.style
```

Offhand, I'd say because the browser is confused with your variable name;

also, the code would be:

`getElementById('hideme').style.display.....`